# How to prove that if $f \in C^1$ then $(f*g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-t) g(t) d \lambda(t) \in C^1 $?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

We have :

$(f*g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-t) g(t) d \lambda(t) $

with $f$ bounded, $g$ integrable, and $\forall x \in \mathcal{D}$ with $\mathcal{D} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x-t)g(t) | d \lambda(t) < \infty \}$.

We would like to prove that if $f \in C^1$, then, $f*g \in C^1$ and $(f*g)' = f' * g$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "integrable" means Riemannn integrable I don't believe this is true. Assuming we mean the Lebesgue integral, I still suspect we need more hypotheses. If $f$ and $f'$ are bounded then: $$\frac{f*g(x+h)-f*g(x)}{h}
=\int\frac{f(x+h-t)-f(x-t)}{h}g(t)\,dt\to\int f'(x-t)g(t)\,dt$$by dominated convergence. (WLOG $f$ is real-valued; then $|(f(x+h-t)-f(x-t)/h|\le\sup|f'|$ by the Mean Value Theorem.)